VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled error
I integrated multidex on my application, while running the app I am getting VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled. on the log. App is not getting crash, App is opening correctly.
Here is the log,
13:06:07.146 MultiDex                 I  VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
13:06:07.146 MultiDex                 I  Installing application
13:06:07.147 MultiDex                 I  VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
13:06:07.147 MultiDex                 I  Installing application
13:06:07.147 MultiDex                 I  VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.

Here is the way I integrated MultiDex in my application.
Enable MultiDex,
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xx.xxxxxxxx"
    minSdk 29
    targetSdk 33
    versionName "1.0.24.1"
    versionCode 43
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

Adding Dependency,
   dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'                       // Multidex
    }

Creating Application class,
class BaseApp : MultiDexApplication(){

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        "BaseApp=> onCreate()".toLog()
    }
    
}

Applying application class on AndroidManifest.xml file,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="xx.xxxxxxxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".data.application.BaseApp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.XXXXX"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        
        
    </application>

</manifest>


Does this answer your question? How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library

multidex is "built-in" since Android 5.0 (sdk 21), your minSdk is higher, so you don't need support library
DOC source, essence:

Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher uses a runtime called ART that natively supports loading multiple DEX files from APK files. ART performs pre-compilation at app install time, scanning for classesN.dex files and compiling them into a single OAT file for execution by the Android device. Therefore, if your minSdkVersion is 21 or higher, multidex is enabled by default and you don't need the multidex library.

